# Why might gunicorn be hanging in this configuration?

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, gunicorn

I'm building a multi-container application using Docker. Everything works well with the Django (1.7) dev server. But when I try to run gunicorn the command `gunicorn wsgi:application` seems to start, then provides no output and keeps control of the terminal until I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. This regrettably means I have little useful debugging information.

My API's Dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Garry Cairns
ENV REFRESHED_AT 2015-01-13

# update packages and prepare to build software
RUN ["apt-get", "update"]
RUN ["apt-get", "-y", "install", "build-essential", "vim", "git", "curl"]
RUN ["locale-gen", "en_GB.UTF-8"]

# install latest python
RUN ["apt-get", "-y", "build-dep", "python3-dev", "python3-imaging"]
RUN ["apt-get", "-y", "install", "python3-dev", "python3-imaging", "python3-pip"]

# prepare postgreSQL support
RUN ["apt-get", "-y", "build-dep", "python3-psycopg2"]

# create a python user to run our programs
RUN ["groupadd", "-r", "python"]
RUN ["useradd", "-r", "-g", "python", "python"]
WORKDIR /home/python
ADD ./ /home/python

# manage requirements
ENV REQUIREMENTS_REFRESHED_AT 2015-02-09
RUN ["pip3", "install", "-r", "requirements.txt"]
```

My production settings (broadly the cookiecutter django defaults) are like this at the moment:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Production Configurations

- Use djangosecure
- Use Amazon's S3 for storing static files and uploaded media
- Use sendgrid to send emails
- Use MEMCACHIER on Heroku
'''
from configurations import values

# See: http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#settings
try:
    from S3 import CallingFormat
    AWS_CALLING_FORMAT = CallingFormat.SUBDOMAIN
except ImportError:
    # TODO: Fix this where even if in Dev this class is called.
    pass

from .common import Common


class Production(Common):

    # INSTALLED_APPS
    INSTALLED_APPS = Common.INSTALLED_APPS
    # END INSTALLED_APPS

    # SECRET KEY
    SECRET_KEY = "Change me" # values.SecretValue()
    # END SECRET KEY

    # django-secure
    INSTALLED_APPS += ("djangosecure", )

    # set this to 60 seconds and then to 518400 when you can prove it works
    SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 60
    SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = values.BooleanValue(True)
    SECURE_FRAME_DENY = values.BooleanValue(True)
    SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = values.BooleanValue(True)
    SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = values.BooleanValue(True)
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = values.BooleanValue(False)
    SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = values.BooleanValue(True)
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = values.BooleanValue(True)
    # end django-secure

    # SITE CONFIGURATION
    # Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
    # END SITE CONFIGURATION

    INSTALLED_APPS += ("gunicorn", )

    # STORAGE CONFIGURATION
    # See: http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html
    INSTALLED_APPS += (
        'storages',
    )

    # See: http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#settings
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

    # See: http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#settings
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "test" # values.SecretValue()
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "test" # values.SecretValue()
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "test" # values.SecretValue()
    AWS_AUTO_CREATE_BUCKET = True
    AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False

    # AWS cache settings, don't change unless you know what you're doing:
    AWS_EXPIRY = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    AWS_HEADERS = {
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=%d, s-maxage=%d, must-revalidate' % (
            AWS_EXPIRY, AWS_EXPIRY)
    }

    # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url
    STATIC_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    # END STORAGE CONFIGURATION

    # EMAIL
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = values.Value('Correspondence <noreply@example.com>')
    EMAIL_HOST = values.Value('smtp.sendgrid.com')
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "test" # values.SecretValue(environ_prefix="", environ_name="SENDGRID_PASSWORD")
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = "test" # values.SecretValue(environ_prefix="", environ_name="SENDGRID_USERNAME")
    EMAIL_PORT = values.IntegerValue(587, environ_prefix="", environ_name="EMAIL_PORT")
    EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = values.Value('[Correspondence] ', environ_name="EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX")
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
    # END EMAIL

    # TEMPLATE CONFIGURATION
    # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs
    TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
        ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', (
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
        )),
    )
    # END TEMPLATE CONFIGURATION

    # CACHING
    # Only do this here because thanks to django-pylibmc-sasl and pylibmc
    # memcacheify is painful to install on windows.
    try:
        # See: https://github.com/rdegges/django-heroku-memcacheify
        from memcacheify import memcacheify
        CACHES = memcacheify()
    except ImportError:
        CACHES = values.CacheURLValue(default="memcached://127.0.0.1:11211")
    # END CACHING
```

Those interested could also check out the [full project source](https://github.com/garry-cairns/correspondence). Anyone know what's going wrong here? Or even a way I can get more useful debugging information?

Comment: Can you run another process in your container to get more info? (`docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> /bin/bash`

Comment: @JavierCortejoso Yes I can run bash in the container. That's where I'm trying to run gunicorn from. Let me know what information might help you and I'll update.

Comment: Can you post the `gunicorn` command you're running?

Comment: @Alex Added now. I'm running `gunicorn wsgi:application` from the same directory as wsgi.py and manage.py.

Comment: @GarryCairns What happens if you add a `--bind` flag? I.e. `gunicorn wsgi:application --bind:0.0.0.0:80`

Comment: @Alex As you've written it I get 'unrecognized arguments'. Putting the bind before 'wsgi:application' I get the same result as before.

Comment: @Alex after going away from this and fixing some other stuff, I've now found that binding does work as you suggested! Don't know why it wasn't before. If you post this as an answer I'll be happy to accept.

Comment: @GarryCairns will do. If it's relevant or a common error, would you mind sharing the other stuff you fixed as well, for future people?

Comment: @Alex I'm still trying to puzzle that one out! It may have something to do with using the command in my fig file rather than a shell but I'll need to test.

Comment: @GarryCairns Hmm, interesting. Good luck! Let me know if I can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `--bind` flag with gunicorn.

Example:

```
gunicorn wsgi:application --bind:0.0.0.0:80
```